# kwic() function returns less rows than it should

Tags: r, nlp, tokenize, quanteda

I'm currently trying to perform a sentiment analysis on a `kwic` object, but I'm afraid that the `kwic()` function does not return all rows it should return. I'm not quite sure what exactly the issue is which makes it hard to post a reproducible example, so I hope that a detailed explanation of what I'm trying to do will suffice.

I subsetted the original dataset containing speeches I want to analyze to a new data frame that only includes speeches mentioning certain keywords. I used the following code to create this subset:

```
ostalgie_cluster <- full_data %>%
  filter(grepl('Schwester Agnes|Intershop|Interflug|Trabant|Trabi|Ostalgie',
                speechContent,
                ignore.case = TRUE))
```

The resulting data frame consists of 201 observations. When I perform `kwic()` on the same initial dataset using the following code, however, it returns a data frame with only 82 observations. Does anyone know what might cause this? Again, I'm sorry I can't provide a reproducible example, but when I try to create a reprex from scratch it just.. works...

```
#create quanteda corpus object
qtd_speeches_corp <- corpus(full_data,
                            docid_field = "id",
                            text_field = "speechContent")

#tokenize speeches
qtd_tokens <- tokens(qtd_speeches_corp, 
                     remove_punct = TRUE,
                     remove_numbers = TRUE,
                     remove_symbols = TRUE,
                     padding = FALSE) %>%
  tokens_remove(stopwords("de"), padding = FALSE) %>%
  tokens_compound(pattern = phrase(c("Schwester Agnes")), concatenator = " ")

ostalgie_words <- c("Schwester Agnes", "Intershop", "Interflug", "Trabant", "Trabi", "Ostalgie")

test_kwic <- kwic(qtd_tokens,
                  pattern = ostalgie_words,
                  window = 5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something of a guess without having a reproducible example (your input `full_data`, namely) but here's my best guess. Your `kwic()` call is using the default "glob" pattern matching, and what you want is a regular expression match instead.

Fix it this way:

```r
kwic(qtd_tokens, pattern = ostalgie_words, valuetype = "regex", 
     window = 5
```